module has no attribute OOP in python
I'm very new to OOP in python.
I wrote a python script which takes an input file and plots some data from it. Now I want to make the same plots for several different data files, so I thought I'd make my script into a class.
This class lives in a file called TargetRunAnalyser.py and goes like this so far:
from ROOT import TFile, TCanvas
import os, sys

def tot_event_waveforms(root_file):
    sd = root_file.Get("Target/Waveforms")
    NEvents=0
    for keyname in sd.GetListOfKeys():
        NEvents+=1
    NEvents/=32
    return NEvents

class TargetRunAnalyser:

    x_channels = [8,7,9,6,10,5,11,4,12,3,13,2,14,1,15,0]
    y_channels = [27,28,26,29,25,30,24,31,23,16,22,17,21,18,20,19]
    
    intersection = set(x_channels) & set(y_channels)
    
    if len(x_channels) != 16 or len(y_channels) != 16:
        print(f"x_channel array length: {len(x_channels)}, y_channel array length: {len(y_channels)}")
        raise Exception("Check channel arrays, they should both have 16 elements")
    
    if len(intersection) !=0:
        raise Exception(f"The following channels are in both x and y: {intersection}")
    
    def __init__(self,run_no):
        self.run_no = run_no
        self.file_path=os.path.join("/Users/bethlong/Downloads/", f"Run{self.run_no}_HistoFile.root")
        self.root_file = TFile(self.file_path,"read")
        self.n_event_print = 100

        #check how many events you have waveforms for so that you don't print more
        n_event_tot = tot_event_waveforms(self.root_file)

        if self.n_event_print>n_event_tot:
            self.n_event_print = n_event_tot

    def canvas_creator(self, canv_name):
        my_canvas = TCanvas("mycanv","mycanv",900,700)
        return my_canvas

I call this class in a separate file which goes like this:
import TargetRunAnalyser
import ROOT

def main():
    RunsToAnalyse = [50252,50305]
    Analysers = [TargetRunAnalyser.TargetRunAnalyser(run) for run in RunsToAnalyse]
    print([i_Analyser.n_event_print for i_Analyser in Analysers])

    canvas_x_signals = TargetRunAnalyser.canvas_creator("x_signals")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

But I get the error:
    canvas_x_signals = TargetRunAnalyser.canvas_creator("x_signals")
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'TargetRunAnalyser' has no attribute 'canvas_creator'

Can anyone tell me why TargetRunAnalyser.TargetRunAnalyser(run) is fine but TargetRunAnalyser.canvas_creator("x_signals") isn't?

TargetRunAnalyser is a class - that is roughly recipe for creating objects (object = TargetRunAnalyser(run). Method canvas_creator exists on this object, not on class. If you want it to exists on class you have to annotate it by putting @classmethod on line above def canvas_creator.

Firstly you are using canvas_creator() like a @staticmethod, so you should mark it as such. Secondly you would need to call it like this: TargetRunAnalyser.TargetRunAnalyser.canvas_creator("x_signals") as TargetRunAnalyser is the name of the module.

You've got a module with the same name as class. canvas_creator is a method of a class, and you are trying to access it directly from a module level. Additionally, I'd suggest going over some tutorial for OOP in Python - you shouldn't have so much code (conditional clauses especially) in class body.

@matszwecja so you think I should create a function above the class which does the lines from intersection to the second raise Exception()? Should I call this function in the __init__?

To be fair, you are defining fixed lists x_channels and y_channels. There is no way for any of those conditions to happen, because at that moment there is no way for those lists to be anything other then what you define them as.

Yes, I know that's true but I want to avoid the possibility that I accidentally change something and don't realise. It's unlikely, but I just want to be warned if I do. Is the setting of n_event_print inside the class ok? Or is that something that should be outsourced to a separate function too? I thought since it was just a few lines of code it was easier to read if it was directly there, but if it's better practice i'll move it


Can anyone tell me why TargetRunAnalyser.TargetRunAnalyser(run) is fine

This works because the first TargetRunAnalyser refers to the module, and the second TargetRunAnalyser refers to the class that is in the module.

but TargetRunAnalyser.canvas_creator("x_signals") isn't?

This doesn't work because TargetRunAnalyser refers only to the module, not the class.
It might be clearer to name the module something else, so the module and the class do not have identical names.

Ok, I renamed the class class RunAnalysis, and now I have:
from TargetRunAnalyser import RunAnalysis
def main():
Analysers = [RunAnalysis(run) for run in RunsToAnalyse]
canvas_x_signals = RunAnalysis.canvas_creator("x_signals")
But I get TypeError: RunAnalysis.canvas_creator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'canv_name'

@BethLong That's because you're using the class directly, but canvas_creator() needs an instance of the class.

Yes ok, so it should be:
canvas_x_signals = [analyser.canvas_creator(f"x_signals_{analyser.run_no}") for analyser in Analysers] since I created the instances of the classes in the first list comprehension.
